# Prevent Spring Security from 302 redirecting after login/logout

Tags: java, spring, apache, tomcat, spring-security

After successful login, or logout, and after failed authentication, there is a redirect to j_spring_security_check with status code 302.

How can I prevent this request?

Screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone still want to change the default name:

Add the attribute login-processing-url, and give your own name (the default is j_spring_security_check).

```
<security:form-login
                login-page="/login"
                authentication-failure-url="/login/401"
                username-parameter="user"
                password-parameter="pass"
                default-target-url="/"
                always-use-default-target="true"
                login-processing-url="/check"/>
```

And then in the login form:

```
action="<c:url value='/check' />"
```

And do the same for logout:

```
<security:logout
                logout-success-url="..."
                invalidate-session="..."
                delete-cookies="..."
                logout-url="/logout"/>
```

Comment: If  `j_spring_security_check` is neither mentioned in the login form nor in the security xml file, then where does `j_spring_security_check` come into play?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can solve this issue by making two actions,one for desktop browsers and other for mobile app.And after getting logout request from mobile apps on the server side you can avoid redirection.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you want to do instead, but you could send your login form data as an AJAX request instead of a form post.

Otherwise, [there are some suggestions here](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/security/81440-spring-login-without-being-redirected)

Comment: It's because of security reasons. I don't want to show I'm using Spring Security. Can I rename it?

Comment: There are other ways that one can see that you're using Spring Security. Security tokens and such.

Comment: Security by obscurity is not a good idea, you won't be able to hide it.

Comment: Spring security 4+ uses `login`. But what mikeb says is true ;)